# Not able to set state in React Hooks using data received from Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am creating a login form using React Hooks and querying the backend using Axios. On successful login I am redirecting to the home page which is working. The problem is on unsuccessful attempt, I want to set the loginFailed to true and do the conditional rendering on the form based on this. **But unfortunately setLoginFailed is not working.**

This is what I am doing on the client side:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers'
import * as yup from "yup"
import axios from 'axios'
import './Login.css'

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup.string().required("Please enter Username."),
  password: yup.string().required("Please enter Password.")
})

export default function Login() {

  const [loginFailed, setLoginFailed] = useState(null);

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  })

  const history = useHistory();

  const onSubmit = data => {
    axios.post('/login', data)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.success) {
        history.push("/")
      } else {
        setLoginFailed(true)
      }
    })
  }

  return (
     
    <form className="login-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      
      {loginFailed && <p>Invalid Username/Password.</p>}

      <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" ref={register} />
      <p className="error">{errors.mobile?.message}</p>
        
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ref={register} />
      <p className="error">{errors.password?.message}</p>
      
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

And this on the server side:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var passport = require('passport')
var Farmer = require('../models/farmer')


router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) { 
      return res.json({success: false}) 
    }
    if (!user) { 
      return res.json({success: false}) 
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err) {
      if (err) { 
        return res.json({success: false}) 
      }
      return res.json({success: true})
    })
  })(req, res, next)
})

module.exports = router
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I set my state on the client side properly?

Comment: Can you confirm from React DevTools if the value of loginFailed is being set to true when you enter wrong login details?

Comment: It stays null even on wrong login details

Comment: Does it enter the else branch tho? Try `console.log` something before calling `setLoginFailed`?

Comment: Yes, check if it enters the else block. If it doesn't, need to debug the server code. Also, always do handle errors inside a .catch

Comment: yes it enters the else block but setLoginFailed doesn't seem to have any effect

Comment: I will definitely catch the server errors in the catch block but this is not an error. its just an invalid credential case.

Comment: The code here is fine, it should be working. Are you *certain* that `setLoginFailed(true)` is called? Perhaps try swapping it with `alert('hello!')` and seeing if that alert displays when you enter incorrect login details?

Comment: Make sure you initialise your variable consistently. `const [loginFailed, setLoginFailed] = useState(false);` – don't initialise it as `null`.

Comment: ok I will set it as false

Comment: So, did you already managed to solve this problem or still stuck on it?

Comment: I changed my strategy and currently using useContext

Comment: @Chandan Kumar answer correctly , I just want to tell you that try to avoid using null instead write false or true or any other value just because it's can do some problem in some situations

Answer (score 3):

I recreated your app locally and everything looked fine, except the name you're using for "Mobile Number" input. In your `yup` schema, you have `username`, while the name of the input is `mobile`. So you have to change one of them to the other.

In my example, it meant `yup` didn't consider the submission valid and never submitted anything to the API. Unless the code in the question is different from your actual code, `onSubmit` should never happen. I'm curious how your code got into `axios.then`.

Anyhow, here's a working example:

`App.js`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers'
import * as yup from "yup"
import axios from 'axios'

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  username: yup.string().required("Please enter Username."),
  password: yup.string().required("Please enter Password.")
})

export default function Login() {

  const [loginFailed, setLoginFailed] = useState(false);

  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  })

  const history = useHistory();

  const onSubmit = data => {
    axios.post('http://0.0.0.0:5000/login', data)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.success) {
          history.push("/")
        } else {
          setLoginFailed(true)
        }
      })
      .catch(console.log)
  }

  return (
     
    <form className="login-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      
      {loginFailed && <p>Invalid Username/Password.</p>}

      <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Mobile Number" ref={register} />
      <p className="error">{errors.mobile?.message}</p>
        
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" ref={register} />
      <p className="error">{errors.password?.message}</p>
      
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
  )
}
```

`server.js`:

```
const cors = require('cors')
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()


router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  return res.json({ success: false })
})

var app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.options('*', cors())
app.use('/', router)

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${5000}`)
})
```

Note that I added `catch` to `axios.post` to handle errors and didn't recreate the `passport` stuff and just returned `{success: false}` to test the code.
Also, as it's mentioned in the comments, it's better to initialize your boolean state with `false` and not `null`.

Comment: ah my bad! that was a typo while posting the question here in stackoverflow. I used mobile in both the form as well as yup. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Comment: @SaprativaBhattacharjee If you got your answer, then accept it so that it can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with using a form tag.

You will need to modify your form submit action as

```
const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   handleSubmit(onSubmit);
}
<form className="login-form" onSubmit={(e) => handleFormSubmit(e)}>
...
...
</form>
```

By default on form submit action it triggers a reload action which is causing the issue in your case.